# ADD failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder673702145/target/xxx.jar: no such file or directory

Tags: java, docker, spring-boot, jar, docker-image

I got the following issue while trying to create a docker image from openjdk base image.

```
ADD ${JAR_FILE} websocket-demo.jar
ADD failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder673702145/target/websocket-demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar: no such file or directory
```

Actually I was following [this](https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-docker-example/%22this%22) tutorial and got this issue while trying to compile Docker file.

Here is my docker file :

```
# Start with a base image containing Java runtime
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

# Add Maintainer Info
LABEL maintainer="Nuibb<*****@gmail.com>"

# Add a volume pointing to /tmp
VOLUME /tmp

# Make port 8080 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 8080

# The application's jar file
ARG JAR_FILE=target/websocket-demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

# Add the application's jar to the container
ADD ${JAR_FILE} websocket-demo.jar

# Run the jar file 
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/websocket-demo.jar"]
```

Can you please let me know how can I fix this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

I am writing this answer if someone else faced this issue and had made a very amateur mistake like mine.

I faced this issue because I had `<packaging>war</packaging>` in my pom.xml and was trying to add a jar file in my docker context with a line like this (ADD ${JAR_FILE} xxx-xxx.jar).

So, a simple fix of changing my line in the pom.xml file to 
`<packaging>jar</packaging>` did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/dockerfile-copy-vs-add-key-differences-and-best-practices-9570c4592e9e

Change `ADD ${JAR_FILE} websocket-demo.jar`
for  `ADD ${JAR_FILE} ${directo}`

Answer (score 0):

Please try to specify the jar file through the path (build/libs) where I believe .jar was created

So change your code to

```
    # Start with a base image containing Java runtime
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

# Add Maintainer Info
LABEL maintainer="Nuibb<*****@gmail.com>"

# Add a volume pointing to /tmp
VOLUME /tmp

# Make port 8080 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 8080

# The application's jar file
ARG JAR_FILE=build/libs/websocket-demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

# Add the application's jar to the container
ADD ${JAR_FILE} websocket-demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

# Run the jar file 
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/websocket-demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```